# Whats is the command/function to select a radio button in AutoIT script while automating Software Installation

Tags: autoit

I am using AutoIT to automate installation of a software. In a window, I am being shown with 2 radio buttons, say radio1 and radio2.  By default the radio2 is selected. The default control is on radio2 radio button. I have to select the radio1. I am able to make the control go to the radio1  by using Send("{TAB}") as many times so that the control goes to the radio1 but I am not getting what should be the command to click on the first radio button. The SEND("{ENTER}") doesnt work in this condition. Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean by using `Send("{TAB}")` you are able to give focus to the radio buttons (the dotted line) but you can't activate them? If this is the case then you can try `Send("{SPACE}")` to activate the proper radio-button.

Answer (score 1):

As you'd know, using ControlCommand is better practice than Send. I understand that you found it difficult to get the control's ID using AutoIT v3 Window Info, which happens some times. There are some other good window information tools I use in those circumstances: winspector / AccExplorer32.exe / inspect32.exe / WindowHandlePicker.exe.

You have several options:

1) Use the following snippet and increase the number in CLASSNN until you get the right checkbox:

```
ControlCommand("Options", "", "[CLASSNN:Button5]", "Check")
```

2) Some of the window info tools listed above tell you the shortcut key for the control (eg. alt+u). If that's the case, it's sometimes possible to send the shortcut without specifying the control:

```
ControlSend("Options", "", "", "!u")
```

3) Using _[CtrlGetByPos](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/30554-controlid-and-classnamenn-are-changing-from-day-to-day/page__p__218527), get the control's ID/CLASSNN/Handle then use it in a ControlClick.

4) Just use `Send("{SPACE}")` as mrt's mentioned